# Workaround for ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to php programming. I have tried googling and searching this website for a fix to this but I don't know what to even type into google to really find my answer.

I get the error:

```
unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
```

I am unsure what I can do avoid this.I know it is caused by the ['userid'] but I need that as part of my coding.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include ('auth/userInfo.php');

$servername = "example";
$username = "example_1";
$password = "example";
$dbname = "example_enter";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$userprofile['userid'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($userprofile['userid']); 

$sql="INSERT INTO today (accessed)
VALUES ('$userprofile['userid']')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Success";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

In case my coding is so bad that no one knows what it is attempting to do. I am attempting to write to a MySQL DB when a user has signed in.

Comment: it starts with this line `$userprofile['userid'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($userprofile['userid']);` and where's this populated from `$userprofile['userid']`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is populated from a json decode of data from another site. Also what do you mean by `it starts with this line $userprofile['userid'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($userprofile['userid']);`?

Comment: ok, well have a look at the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php there's an important thing you're not doing.

Comment: you're welcome. However, the answer given below doesn't cover what I said about `mysqli_real_escape_string()` so it should be adjusted for future users to see it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that you are (a) using quotes to reference an array index inside a literal string (b) inserting a line break inside that same string:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO today (accessed)
VALUES ('$userprofile['userid']')";
```

What you probably meant to write is:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO today (accessed) VALUES ('" . $userprofile['userid'] . "')";
```

However even this is problematic due to SQL injection attacks - I recommend you read up on parameterized queries (`mysqli_prepare`).

Comment: that's not the only thing. they've forgotten an important factor in their mysqli_real_escape_string() function http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Thanks :) the userid is set by us so it can't be manipulated to be harmful.

Comment: @DickQueef It's set only by your code **now**. What happens in a few years when you need to expose it via an API? Coding defensively is always the wisest choice, it doesn't take any extra time and it makes your code far more robust.

Comment: can you please adjust your answer so that it reflects **all** the problems here?

Comment: why are my comments being ignored?